# callback not called when value is set

Tags: matlab, callback

I have a gui in matlab with a listbox. If I fill this listbox and set its index value the callback is not called:

```
set(handles.listboxColors, 'String', listboxEntryList, 'Value', 1 );
```

Here I expect that the callback

```
function listboxColors_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
```

is called, which does not happen.

Answer (score 1):

Normal [Callback](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/creating_guis/writing-code-for-callbacks.html#f16-999626) controls action, triggers only when when a user clicks a push button or selects a menu item.

A `set` of `Value` property of  `listbox` property won't trigger the callback mentioned.

One way to achieve this will be using

```
guidata(hObject, handles);

listboxColors_Callback(hObject,eventdata,handles);
```

after setting `Value` in your function.

Comment: Sure, but I want the callback to be called when a value is set.

Comment: Are you calling the `set` in some other callback ?

Comment: That is very likely. Mostly the callback itself call a function. Here it would be `updateListColors`, which fills the list and sets the value at the end.